# different color light source on object with "shader to rgb" node

Tags: lighting, shader-nodes

I'm using this node setup to achieve the artwork look you see to the left. Probably bc of the shader to rgb node, the light sources individual colors are not being shown. Everything takes on the colors I define in the color ramp. I would however like to add a "kicker" light from the back that is maybe pink or green. Is this in any way possible with this setup? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fake lighting by using the normal of your object, like this :

[image]

However, this technique won't give you accurate shadows, as all the faces pointing in the direction you chose will be illuminated, even when the light source should be blocked : [image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That's quite interesting to play around with.

Comment: I got a follow up question:
Since all faces at a certain direction are affected, I get the fake light color show up at places where it makes no sense physically, like the nose.
could I somehow limit the range in a way that it only shows up on the backside of the model? as if the light would cut off half way through the body and doesn't make it to the front, if that description makes any sense.

Comment: You can paint vertex color on your mesh and use it as a mask in the shader editor. Here's an old video that shows just that : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrzjhDsXRDs

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to search that!
I'm just super bad at thinking in nodes and I can't figure out, where to plug the vertex color node to.
I painted the face black, to potentially exclude it from the "kicker light".
Any suggestion?

Comment: No problem, it's fairly easy. He does it in the video at 2:02 : he adds a node "Atribute", which points to an attribute named "Col". That's the name of the Vertex Color data he created when he paintend on his model. This node now holds the color data you painted, and you can use it as a mask in your node tree. One way to do it is to use a Math node set to multiply on the result of the Normal node. Areas in white will be multiplied by 1 (no change). Areas in black will be multiplied by 0 (so transformed into black).

Comment: Here's a file where I've done just that : https://blend-exchange.com/b/GygB1xLN

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it to work. I would just never have thought about adding another Map Range Node and combine them with Multiply. My brain just can't speak nodisch.

Comment: Haha, when the logic will quick in you'll become bilingual in no time ! Keep up the good work !